# Problem in understanding PDE solution

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

I solved the PDE shown below and I got the solution. I am new to this tool. In the solution, I have a constant multiplied by a vector like function  (please refer second term of the solution). What does it mean ? Appreciate your help. Thanks

```
pde = c1*D[u[x, y, z], x] + c2*D[u[x, y, z], y] + c3*D[u[x, y, z], z] +
a*u[x, y, z] - p == 0

soln = DSolve[pde, u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before we go to the PDE you solved, consider the following pde straight from the from the documentation.

```
DSolve[3 D[y[x1, x2], x1] + 5 D[y[x1, x2], x2] == x1, y[x1, x2], {x1, x2}]
```

> ```
> {{y[x1, x2] -> 1/6 (x1^2 + 6 C[1][1/3 (-5 x1 + 3 x2)])}}
> ```

`DSolve` can solve both ODEs and PDEs with/without boundary conditions. When we don't give boundary conditions, results have arbitrary constants (for ODEs) and arbitrary functions (for PDEs). In the example above, we have a PDE with two independent variables (`x1` & `x2`) and no boundary conditions are given; therefore, the solution has an arbitrary function `C[1]` (of one argument). This function is  `C[1][1/3 (-5 x1 + 3 x2)]`.

Now, in the PDE you solved you have three independent variables (`x`, `y` & `z`) and, therefore, the arbitrary function in the solution has two arguments. `C[1][(-c2 x + c1 y)/c1, (-c3 x + c1 z)/c1]`.